# How to perform a many-to-many query with SQLBoiler

Tags: go, orm, many-to-many, sqlboiler

I'm using [SQLBoiler](https://github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler) as my golang ORM.

I'm trying to query a user and all of his roles, to do that I have the following tables:

ROLES:

```
role_id  desc   name
1        basic  basic
```

USERS:

```
user_id password    user_name   created_at  updated_at  updated_by ...
1        ...        ...         ...         ...         ...
```

USERS_ROLES:

```
id  user_id role_id
1   1       1
foreign keys: user_id, role_id
```

I'm trying to query (without using sql query) a user and all of his roles in the following way:

```
func getUserRoles(user *models.USERS) (models.USERROLESSlice, error) {
    if roles, err := user.UserUSERROLESS().All(context.Background(), DB); err != nil {
        infra.LogError("failed to query user roles", err)
        return nil, err
    } else {
        return roles, nil
    }
}
```

which gives me models.USERROLESSlice instead of slice of models.ROLES
that contain my joining table.

or to just use:

```
   if usr, err := models.USERSS(qm.Where(query, req.Email, req.Password),qm.Load("ROLES")).One(context.Background(), DB); err != nil && err.Error() == "sql: no rows in result set" {
        infra.LogInfo(fmt.Sprintf("no result for %s", req.Email))
        return nil, nil
    }
```

as I would have done if I had any other object-relationship
but non of those give me the result I expect.

any one know what is the easy & elegant way to do it?

Edit:
For now I just used qm.SQL to get forward

```
    if roles, err := models.ROLESS(qm.SQL("SELECT roles.* FROM user_roles INNER JOIN roles ON user_roles.role_id = roles.role_id WHERE user_roles.user_id=@uid", user.UserID)).All(context.Background(), DB); err != nil {
    infra.LogError("failed to query user roles", err)
    return nil, err
}
```

but again I'm looking for the elegant way, you can find some examples in the following link:
https://github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler

Comment: `err.Error() == "sql: no rows in result set"` -> `err == sql.ErrNoRows` https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#pkg-variables

Comment: Could you shows us what your models look like? Based on the library's documentation, it looks like you should be able to do something like `user.ROLESS.All()`.

Comment: I updated my post, I added link at the top and one at the end

Comment: I was able to find the library and was commenting on what it looks like you should be able to do based on its documentation. Are you able to show us what your generated models look like?

Comment: @Gavin first of all thank you, sadly it's kind of long to just copy paste it, but It will be easy simulate using a simple many-to-many scheme.
if you have sqllite installed i can edit my post and add the needed sql to generate the necessary tables